# MySQL Query Multiple Joins with Incorrect Results

Tags: php, sql, mysql, join

I have 3 tables structured like so:

**activity table:**

> activity_id, user_id, type, date

**reviews table:**

> review_id, activity_id, fishery_id, review, date

**updates table:**

> update_id, activity_id, update, date

I want to call the all the reviews and updates which are linked to a user by the activity table however this query returns incorrect results, any ideas?

```
query('
  SELECT *
  FROM activity as activity    
  LEFT JOIN reviews AS reviews
    ON activity.activity_id = reviews.activity_id    
  LEFT JOIN updates AS updates
    ON activity.activity_id = updates.activity_id    
  WHERE user_id = 1
');
```

Thanks, Matt

Comment: What sort of 'incorrect results'?  Did you remember to make sure distinct columns from distinct tables have different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to select two different sets of data, the only way I can thing of doing this in one SQL statement, is to use a union, and create some extra columns to tell the difference.

```
SELECT 'review' as type,r.review_id as id,r.fishery_id as fid,
    r.review as review,null as update,r.date as date
FROM reviews r,activity a
WHERE r.activity_id=a.activity_id AND a.user_id=@user_id

UNION

SELECT 'updates' as type,u.update_id as id,null as fid,
    null as review,u.update update,u.date as date
FROM updates u,activity a
WHERE u.activity_id=a.activity_id AND a.user_id=@user_id
```

Comment: I tried this originally which returns no results, I have put "EXPLAIN" at the start of the query and its saying "Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables" and ideas?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry you're using `activity_id` as the id in the activity table, not `id` {Updated}

Comment: I've got the query to work now using UNION and NULL to balance out the difference in column numbers! Thanks Guys! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want reviews and updates in the same rows, which appears to be what you are trying to do.  So, you need two queries, not one, which would be:

```
SELECT r.review_id, r.fishery_id, r.review, r.date
FROM   reviews r
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM activity a
               WHERE  a.user_id = @user_id
               AND    a.activity_id = r.activity_id)

SELECT u.update_id, u.update, u.date
FROM   update u
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM activity a
               WHERE  a.user_id = @user_id
               AND    a.activity_id = u.activity_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference the working query:

```
  SELECT type, review_id, activity.activity_id, review, activity.date, fishery_id
  FROM activity as activity
  JOIN reviews AS reviews
    ON activity.activity_id = reviews.activity_id

  UNION

  SELECT type, activity_id, activity.activity_id, activity, activity.date, NULL
  FROM activity as activity
  JOIN activity AS activity
    ON activity.activity_id = activity.activity_id

  WHERE activity.user_id = 1

  ORDER BY date DESC
```